# How to perform Prestashop Multishop redirection based on country

Tags: prestashop

I have created two shops with in a same domain for my prestashop site.One for the customers belong to my country and other shop for international customers.How to redirect the customer to my multishop based on the country from which they are opening?

Comment: You need to check the customer ip (can be done with the "geoip" library) and redirect it to the right store. But this isn't standart functional, so you need the custom solution for this purpose.

Comment: Is it possible by fetching the country code from geolocation module available in prestashop..  @Alexander Simonchik

Comment: What exactly module did you mean? I can't have any geolocation module in my standard PS 1.6

Comment: In my prestashop ver 1.5.4.1 i am having the geolocation module.I have installed the module and make it enable and marked the location too.@AlexanderSimonchik